# How can I handle multiple input fields generated dynamically in php using POST

Tags: php, html

This is the html/php code

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="POST">
    <div id="input">
        <label for="package">Package</label>
        <input type="text" name="package[]">
        <label for="price">Price</label>
        <input type="text" name="price[]">
        <input type="button" value="add" onClick="addInput('input');">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Package">
    </div>
</form>
```

this is JS

```
function addInput(parentDiv) {
    let newInput = document.createElement('div');
    newInput.innerHTML = '<label for="package">Package</label> <input type="text" name="package"> <label for="price">Price</label> <input type="text" name="price"></input>';
    document.getElementById(parentDiv).appendChild(newInput);
}
```

The user is allowed to add as many inputs as possible. I would like to capture them in an array, with the package as the key and price as the value and save to an sql table

Comment: What have you tried on the PHP side? Have you looked at e.g. `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: no, I used  $_POST['name']. This way, I only get the last value provided by the user

Comment: There's no field called `name` in the code you've posted.

Comment: the name is just a placeholder. I used `$_POST['package']`

Comment: Could you show us the creation of the extra inputs via the JS function `addInput`?

Comment: This is the js `function addInput(parentDiv) {
 let newInput = document.createElement('div');
 newInput.innerHTML =
  '<label for="package">Package</label> <input type="text" name="package"> <label for="price">Price</label> <input type="text" name="price"></input>';
 document.getElementById(parentDiv).appendChild(newInput);
}`

Comment: You're missing the `[]` braces from the names in that code, which is why your data won't be posted as an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are inserting your HTML, you are giving everything the same name. When this is then submitted, the web server isn't quite sure which one you want so it only uses 1 of these values - in your case it seems to be the very last one.

If you change the names of your controls to add `[]` at the end (e.g. `<input type="text" name="package[]">`), the server then treats this as an array and you are able to obtain all the values.

If you then do `var_dump($_POST)` from your PHP you should see an array of values for package and price. Then, server-side we can just loop through those.

```php
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['package']); $i++){
    $package = $_POST['package'][$i];
    $price = $_POST['price'][$i];
    //do whatever you want with variables here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

in your php code when processing package and price you should use an foreach cycle, look below example (here I suppose the package and price arrays have the same size and it's not associative arrays). Use foreach to cycle through arrays.

```
$i = 0;
for($_POST['package'] as $package) {
    $price = $_POST['price'][$i];
    //your sql insert of package&price couple
    $i++
}
```